# relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against `_ZN7QStringD1Ev' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

Tags: qtwebkit

When I build qtwebkit, I got this problem.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /data/zhengjie/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1/qtmultimedia/lib/libQt5Multimedia.a(qmediametadata.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against `_ZN7QStringD1Ev' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [../../lib/libWebCore.so.1.0.0] Error 1
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you recompile with -fPIC as suggested ?

Comment: The Makefile contains the -fPIC option

Comment: When I remove "-fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden" from the CXXFLAGS, it works.
I think that is because ~QString() is inline, the option above hide the destructor, so destructor can't be found.